# Control 4 wheeled raspberry robot with Simulink

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, simulink

I am going to control 4 wh raspberry robot in Simulink. I found this one to control DC motor with simulink: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41528-raspberry-pi-dc-motor-h-bridge-driver-block-sfunction?s_tid=srchtitle It is just for a one motor. My question: is it possible to build a simulink model for 4wheeled robot car by this model? I understood that, by changing to - or + value of block constant motor will drive anticlockwise or clockwise. How to be to turn left or right? It doesn't like Python or C programming, so it's stopped project. Especially for Simulink, any idea or suggestions would be greatly approtiated! Thank you so much in adwance!
I added images which i meant in comment. I am a newbie, so please, don't judge me quality)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A19fP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ngX.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you can put this in a subsystem as motor driver for each motor (maybe you have to adjust the Pins for PWM output for each motor) the logic around to control the robot you have to program by yourself. How do you want to control it? by remote control or by defining a trajectory it should follow? First might be quite simple, for second you need to build a mathematical model of your system like [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/amc/amc14/amc1445.pdf)

Comment: @Berger Thank you so much for prompt replying! I am going to control it by simple GUI, App builder of Matlab. Where created 4 buttons for each direction of robot: forward, reverse, turn right, turn left.

Comment: @Berger I just copied this model, for each motor(2 of them with "-", to move motor anticlockwise (or reverse) ) . Added Manual-Switch block, between subsystem block and constant, but i feel it's not correct. Unfortunately, I have not privilage to add photo to show it.

Comment: There is also a block where you can use a controller see [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7KkciHn0jc) or [matlab webinar](https://de.mathworks.com/videos/using-gamepadcontroller-for-simulation-input-79220.html). I've never used the library for the motors, but what is your problem now? Do the motors turn or not?

Comment: @Berger, Thank you so much for advices and replying! Yes, I saw some webinars and lessons, also mathwork's website is also full of various tutorials. I should to program for robot itself (it is already built robot and i should to program it. I know, it is not clear, but I don't have a choice). I am bad. Unfortunately, i don't have a time to build it by checking motor.

Comment: I suggest you first to get one motor to run using the simulink library you mentioned. Do you actually have a H-bridge driver like the DRV8833? With one driver you can control two motors, see [here](https://www.robotgear.com.au/Cache/Files/ProductImageOriginals/1193_DRV8833%20dual%20motor%20driver%20carrier%20-%20Wiring%20diagram.png). You should connect P0 to AIN1 and P7 to AIN2 and connect the motor to AOUT1 and AOUT2 don't forget the ground of the Pi to GND. The power supply for the motors should be connected to GND and VIN. Do you have this?

Comment: @Berger, Yes, I know that i should to first run 1 motor. But as I meant, I don't have a time to run itself. I had to message to owner (Joshua Hurst) of model which shown above link, about driver and motor. I think, it's better to try with Stateflow. Thank you so much anyway! I learnd some new things from you.